# what is the meaning of steroidal?

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of *steroidal* in **steroidal state capitalism**?

My understanding: the adjective *steroidal* means *beyond normal*, according to the explanation of [on steroids](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/steroid).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a more common expression is [on steroids:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/on-steroids)

> bigger, better, louder etc. than other similar things in a way that seems exaggerated and unreal.

So the sense is a state capitalism that is way beyond what is considered  normal practice.

(MacMillan Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

Often steroidal used in this sense relates to Male sex hormones only, and so 'steroidal' here means 'toxic masculinity'.

Comment: Or it's used to refer to muscles which are artificially enlarged due to steroid drug use.

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, and often muscles built up that way are not of much practical use and the body of which they are a part has it's general health compromised. There could be an element of that thinking in the metaphor.